# How to configure base URL for a static website

Tags: html, web-applications, hyperlink, web-hosting, base-url

I have a static website - it has a few HTML, CSS, and js files. I can serve it locally, or I could publish it to a static website server like Netlify or Vercel.

Problem: I want to serve it at a base url. e.g. `www.mydomain.com/baseurl`. So for example, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/style.css">` in `index.html` should be converted to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="baseurl/dist/style.css">` when deployed.

I could rewrite the URLs in all my files, but then it wouldn't work when trying to serve it locally.

How can I configure a base URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move everything into a folder called `baseurl`.

e.g. folder structure

```
- root
  - baseurl
    - index.html
    - dist
       - style.css
```

So, now `www.domain.com/baseurl/index.html`, which rewrites all requests to `/baseurl` to wherever this thing is hosted, should work because any requests for assets all start with `baseurl` and will all be rewritten.

#### Note

I did come across some weird behaviour though which I didn't understand. Say I had the following folder structure:

```
- root
  - baseurl
    - folder
       - index.html
       - markdown.md
       - dist
         - style.css
```

Note that `markdown.md` is on the same level as `index.html` and it is an asset required by `index.html`.

When I go to `www.domain.com/baseurl/folder/index.html` everything works fine.

However, if I go to `www.domain.com/baseurl/folder/index.html` then it complains about not being able to find `www.domain.com/baseurl/markdown.md`. It's looking for the asset in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Only HTML Static website, you can directly link it.

For Example you can use as

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico">`

Just replace `https` or `http` with your base url.

or

Alternative methods are using PHP. But you can try with above code.